# Are View/ViewModel circular dependency references ever appropriate?

Tags: design-patterns, mvvm

I'm reading Mark Seeman's book "Dependency Injection in .NET" again.  In it he describes an adapter type used to provide the view with the appropriate view model, but in the same context also mentions making the view model aware of the view (though something like IWindow) to "control its windowing environment, such as showing modal dialog boxes."

It has been my experience that this is a non-trivial breach of MVVM design, and may even be a poor DI solution.  Most of these sorts of "needs" are often capable of being expressed through a combination of DataTriggers, third party services, mediator patterns, and in some cases, plain old clr events.  (It's worth noting that many people prefer exposing eventlike ViewModel elements through IObserver injection.  [Mark Seeman even blogged on this!](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2013/09/11/di-and-events-composition/)

Therefore I ask the question: **"Regardless of framework, technology, language, stack, or toolset.  If MVVM can be implemented, is there (should there ever be) ANY reason that the View Model need awareness of the view?"**

Followup related question: **"Is there ever justification for ignoring this guidance due to complexity of enforcing the pattern strictly?"**

Comment: honestly, I don't think, anyone can 100% answer this question because there are as many opinions as programmers. Specifically, I don't think this is circular dependency because view model only "aware" of the view via interface but it doesn't know anything about the implementation. Another thing - lots of people go crazy about DI these days but I think, it is way over used out there and seem that Greg Young thinks same way http://www.infoq.com/presentations/8-lines-code-refactoring

Comment: Okay, that's great, but this question has very little to do with dependency injection.  Also, the question is inviting of counterpoints which IS exactly what an answer to this question would be.

Comment: As we know The ViewModel is the bridge between View and Model. Your model is most probably domain specific and UI is always technology specific. ViewModel steps in here and fill the gap. so i am seeing viewmodel and view dependency is more a technology based issue and based what technology you are using , whether it is WPF or JS framework like AngularJS. Seeman mentioned MVVM as an example to how we break an dependency cycle. He is giving a property injection as a solution. It allows you to compose the object graph first then allows to inject the property.

Comment: Actually he doesn't directly suggest property injection here. And again, this question was brought up by seeing his sample, but it isn't the question at hand.  Also, I agree that the dependencies are somewhat related to the technology being implemented, the design pattern is not.

Answer (score 3):

> Regardless of framework, technology, language, stack, or toolset. If
>   MVVM can be implemented, is there (should there ever be) ANY reason
>   that the View Model need awareness of the view?

A ViewModel is the model for the View, not the other way around, so there should not be any awareness (either directly or through an interface) of the View in the ViewModel. The only time I've seen that the ViewModel should be made aware of the View, was because of bad design.

> Is there ever justification for ignoring this guidance due to
>   complexity of enforcing the pattern strictly?

I don't think there is.

A lot of ViewModels look like as if the developers did everything first in the code-behind and then moved all that code-behind logic in a separate class and called it the ViewModel.  You'll see things there like opening popups or deciding how wide a certain control should be.

I think that this is not the way to get the most out of MVVM. UI logic will always be linked to the View. If you use WPF or Silverlight it will be very difficult to get rid of all code in the code-behind.

E.g. showing a modal dialog box is not the responsibility of the ViewModel, it is the UI that decide how to represent a certain condition/event. The condition/event can be found in the ViewModel, but changes to this will be handled by the View.

Comment: And how do you send event from the view to the viewmodel and then to the model? Do you only send events in one direction? No 2-way-bindings? As an example you have a dropdown and the selected option is denoted in the model as selectedNetwork. You need to notify the model somehow. MVVM seems to be kind of circular by design unsell you expose all functions as public, which is a bad design.